# Masonry imageLoaded Wordpress enqueue

Tags: jquery, image, wordpress, jquery-masonry

Damn,

*been on google for a couple of days* now trying to find out how to enqueue and load Masonry plugin imageLoader in my wordpress.

http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/

Here is my enqueue and load of Masonry:

```
    // MASONRY

function anaximander_masonry() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_register_script('jquery_masonry', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/jquery.masonry.min.js', array('jquery'), '2.0.110526' );
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery_masonry');
        add_action('wp_footer', 'anaximander_add_masonry');

        function anaximander_add_masonry() { ?>
            <script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                    $('#masonry-index').masonry({
                        itemSelector: '.index-post-container',
                        isAnimated: true
                    });
                });
            </script>
        <?php 
        }
    }
}

add_action('init', 'anaximander_masonry');
```

*If anyone just could write the enqueue and load of imageLoaded directly here, I would be forever grateful!*

Link to homepage it concern:
http://bergmanphotography.se/photos/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure out a solution that worked. Don't know if the code is really ugly. But it is working. YEY!

```
// IMAGELOADED

    function anaximander_imagesloaded(){
if (!is_admin()) {
    wp_register_script('imagesloaded', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script('imagesloaded');     
    // FlexSlider custom settings       
    add_action('wp_footer', 'anaximander_add_imagesloaded');
    function anaximander_add_imagesloaded() { ?>            
        <script>        
        (function($){
$(window).load(function() {
  // Masonry Trigger
  var $container = $('#masonry-index');

  $container.masonry({
     // options
     itemSelector: '.index-post-container', 
     columnWidth: 283 
  });
}); 
 })(jQuery); 
        </script>
    <?php 
    }
}
}
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'anaximander_imagesloaded');
```